# Is there a short proof of the formula for Legendre symbol $(\frac{2}{p})=(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ > 2 be a prime number. I found in wiki a complex proof for this Legendre symbol: 
$$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)  =  (-1)^{\frac{(p^{2}-1)}{8}}$$

Can anyone give me a **short** solution please?

Comment: Do you mean the proof at ProofWiki? It is almost immediate from Gauss Lemma. Unfortunately, if you start from scratch and have to establish Euler's criterion, then Gauss' Lemma, it is fairly complex. I have not seen a short proof from scratch.

Comment: At least, a short proof for the Gauss lemma is is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(number_theory)), and then the above is an easy application.

Answer (score 4):

Let $s = \frac{p-1}{2}$, and consider the $s$ equations

$$\begin{align}
1&= (-1)(-1)  \\
2&=2(-1)^2  \\
3&= (-3)(-1)^3 \\
4&= 4 (-1)^4 \\
 & \quad\quad \ldots\\
s&= (\pm s)(-1)^s
\end{align}$$

Where the sign is always chosen to have the result be positive.

Now multiply the $s$ equations together. Clearly on the left we have $s!$. On the right, we have a $2,4,6,\dots$ and some negative odd numbers. But note that $2(s) \equiv -1 \mod p$, $2(s-1) \equiv - 3 \mod p$, and so on, so that the negative numbers are the rest of the even numbers mod $p$, but disguised. So the right side contains $s! (2^s)$ (where we intuit this to mean that one two goes to each of the terms of the factorial, to represent the even numbers $\mod p$).

We only have consideration of $(-1)^{1 + 2 + \ldots + s} = (-1)^{s(s+1)/2}$ left.

Putting this all together, we get that $2^s s! \equiv s! (-1)^{s(s+1)/2} \mod p$, or upon cancelling factorials that $2^s \equiv (-1)^{s(s+1)/2}$. And $s(s+1)/2 = (p^2 - 1)/8$, so we really have $2^{(p-1)/2} \equiv (-1)^{(p^2 - 1)/8}$.

Comment: Just upvoted. That is neat. I had not seen it before.

Comment: the right side contains s!(2s), how did you calculate it?

Comment: @MrMado That is the product of the first $s$ even numbers.